# configure does not recognize androideabi

Tags: android-ndk, autotools, configure, autoconf, android-ndk-r5

I am trying to compile a library using android-ndk-r5 standalone toolchain and autotools. When doing a ./configure, it fails with:

```
$ ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi
...snip...
checking host system type... Invalid configuration `arm-linux-androideabi': system `androideabi' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub arm-linux-androideabi failed
```

Explicitly setting CC and CXX does not work either (configure says to use --host).

The NDK docs and various materials online seems to indicate that using the standalone toolchain in this manner should be possible. What is wrong here? and how can I resolve it? (besides simply ditching autoconf and going back to Android.mk)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You might need a newer `config.sub` and `config.guess`, 2010-05-20 or later.

Comment: Yes, apparently my config.sub was 2009-11-20. Replacing with a newer one works. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on this? Do I need to replace those files in the directory of the library I compile? Or a systemwide change? Where do I get these files?

Comment: i do the same thing,but nothing change.Any idea?

Comment: kaiwii@ubuntu:~/test/fuse-2.8.1/fuse-2.8.1$ ./configure CC= arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -host= arm-linux-androideabi –enable-static_link
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type: –enable-static_link
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc': machine `arm-linux-androideabi' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub arm-linux-androideabi-gcc failed

Answer (score 15):

You can get the newer `config.sub` and `config.guess` from [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=tree)

I took the newest from both, but that lead to errors, so I took the mentioned ones of Peter Eisentraut's date.

Answer (score 11):

You can also grab `config.sub` and `config.guess` from the Ubuntu `autotools-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
cp /usr/share/misc/config.{sub,guess} .
```