# how does configure file find the correct cross-compile tools?

Tags: android, configure, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I need to port the ZThread lib to android development environment.

I followed this:
http://blog.jimjh.com/compiling-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk-part-2.html

when i set `--host=arm-eabi` , the configure file checking for `arm-eabi-g++` `arm-eabi-c++`...,but my my cross-compile toolchain is named `arm-linux-androideabi-*`;well ,when i change to `--host=arm-linux-androideabi`,it says system "androideabi" not recognized,i think it is not in config.sub file.

the key is how does configure file find the correct cross-compile tools?

error message is :
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `arm-linux-androideabi': system`androideabi' not recognized

EDIT:
you can try to write Android.mk file for your 3rd lib, android NDK will cross compile the lib for you using the Android.mk file(work just like the makefile). There is a ZThread's Android.mk example, given by my comment

Comment: i meet the same problem with u.And after updating the config.guess and config.sub,it still prompt the same mistake yet.Have u fix the problem?

Comment: if you need cross compile 3rd part lib for android,I suggest u use Android.mk. here is an example [link](http://www.cnblogs.com/maadiah/archive/2012/04/06/2434591.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to update config.*

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/autotools-dev/autotools-dev_20110511.1_all.deb

```
cp -av /usr/share/misc/config.guess ./
cp -av /usr/share/misc/config.sub  ./
```

check :

[configure does not recognize androideabi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594736/configure-does-not-recognize-androideabi)

Answer (score 0):

have you exported the PATH where your cross-compile tools are located?

e.g. in linux you have to add the following line in .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/username/path-to-android-ndk/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
```

in windows you have to add this path to environment variables. Particularly to the the variable named as PATH.