# How to build open source programs with a configure script for Android using NDK?

Tags: android, build, android-ndk, configure, cyanogenmod

I have a question about how to build open source programs with a configure script for Android using NDK?

I have seen something [here](http://warpedtimes.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/building-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk/) but it doesn't seem to be very helpful.

Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277330/how-to-configure-for-building-open-source-library-with-ndk) but it didn't provide much information either.

Are there more detailed information about how to build open source programs with a configure script for Android using NDK?

---

I have a CyanogenMod with a terminal emulator, so I'd like to have a Linux like environment on my Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that with configure scripts that support cross compiling a GNU toolchain can be used.

But Google's NDK seems to lack a lot of things, although by using Google's NDK as a standalone toolchain can accomplish some things. Using NDK I have built `binutils` successfully have not tested if the binaries really work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747734/why-does-arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-give-iostream-error)'s some relevant information.

I'm not sure if there are other prebuilt GNU toolchains.

Answer (score 2):

[This makefile](http://dev.laptop.org/git/users/cscott/android-libs/tree/jni/Makefile.devel) uses the information from the warpedtimes blog post to pass correct parameters to configure script to build for Android NDK.